# When AtomicInteger is faster than synchronized

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, volatile, atomicinteger

I've already read a great number of articles where is said that AtomicInteger class works faster than a synchronize construction. I did some tests on AtomicInteger and "synchronized" and in my tests, it occurs that synchronized is much faster than AtomicInteger. I would like to understand what is going wrong: **my test class is incorrect or AtomicInteger works faster in other situations?**

Here is my test class:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // creating tester "synchronized" class
        TesterSynchronized testSyn = new TesterSynchronized();

        // Creating 3 threads
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(testSyn);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(testSyn);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(testSyn);

        // start time
        long beforeSyn = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // start
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread3.join();

        long afterSyn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long delta = afterSyn - beforeSyn;

        System.out.println("Test synchronized: " + delta + " ms");

        // _______________________________________________________

        // creating tester "atomicInteger" class
        TesterAtomicInteger testAtomic = new TesterAtomicInteger();

        thread1 = new Thread(testAtomic);
        thread2 = new Thread(testAtomic);
        thread3 = new Thread(testAtomic);

        // start time
        long beforeAtomic = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // start
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread3.join();

        long afterAtomic = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long deltaAtomic = afterAtomic - beforeAtomic;

        System.out.println("Test atomic integer: " + deltaAtomic + " ms");
    }
}

// Synchronized tester
class TesterSynchronized implements Runnable {
    public int integerValue = 0;

    public synchronized void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++)
            integerValue++;
    }
}

// AtomicInteger class tester
class TesterAtomicInteger implements Runnable {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++)
            atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Test parameters: 3 threads and 1_000_000 increments;
Result:

> Test synchronized: 7 ms.  Test atomic integer: 51 ms

**I would be glad to understand why this is happening.**

**UPD**
The test will be correct if change the *synchronized method* to a *synchronized block*.

```
// Synchronized tester
class TesterSynchronized implements Runnable {
    public int integerValue = 0;

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            synchronized (this) {
                integerValue++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your synchronised tester you are taking one lock, and then doing your million increments. In your AtomicInteger example you are taking and releasing a lock for each increment.

Comment: Try to wrap the `synchronized` around `integerValue++` and `AtomicInteger` will be faster. You cannot compare the two methods.

Comment: Indeed, it is a problem! After changing to synchronized block the result of the test is: 
Test synchronized: 244 ms
Test atomic integer: 95 ms.

Comment: Besides the mistake with `synchronized`, you should check out how to do [correct benchmarking in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/12323248). In this test here it might be clear that `synchronized` is slower, but in some other tests you want to avoid noise that impacts your results.

Comment: The original TesterSynchronized loop can be optimized by the compiler. There is no point in executing that loop; it can just immediately assign the 1_000_000 to integerValue instead of doing 1M increments.

Comment: I would also use JMH to reduce the chance of obvious benchmarking bugs. And keep in mind that a run of a few ms is very short; the JIT hardly had any time to warm up. Apart from that, the first 4 seconds biased locking (a lock optimization) is disabled which could color the numbers differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious difference in your code is that the `AtomicIntger` version allows interleaving of threads with ever access, whereas the `synchronized` version does the entire loop each thread in turn.

There may be other issues. For instance, the JVM may merge multiple invocations of a `synchronized` block. Depending on the platform, `incrementAndGet` may not be an atomic operation but implemented as a CAS-loop - if contention is high that could be a problem (I am not entirely sure on that).

Whichever way it is arranged, if you have multiple threads concurrently modifying the same memory location it will not be fast.

Comment: "if contention is high that could be a problem (I am not entirely sure on that)", it's the opposite: CAS is especially great when contention is high, because it won't force threads to be blocked.

Comment: @akuzminykh I think the issue is that with multiple concurrent threads can loop because one thread succeeded. Admittedly this is unlikely if the operation is a fast as just an increment, and it may well be implemented with locked load-modify-store.